# Is it possible to optimize this VB.net code ? Can there be a better implementation?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

Please help me optimize this code..

```
Public Sub createNextMonthSheets(ByRef io As InputOutput)
    Dim WB As Excel.Workbook = getWorkBook(io.newClientReportHandle)
    For Each name In clientSheetNames.FindAll(AddressOf findCurrMonthSheetNames)
        For Each sheet In WB.Sheets
            If (sheet.Name = name) Then
                sheet.Name = name.Replace(currMonth, nextMonth)
                sheet.Copy(After:=WB.Sheets(1))
            End If
        Next sheet
    Next name
    WB.Close()
End Sub

Private Function findCurrMonthSheetNames(ByVal sheetName As String) As Boolean
    If sheetName.Contains(" (" + currMonth + ")") Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

I am new to vb.net and don't know the power of this language.

See if you can optimize this on performance !!

See if you can optimize this on fewer lines of code that does the same thing.

You can introduce new aspects of the language that can make this more readable !

Can you overload the findcurrmonthsheetnames function in some way to get the WB.sheets ?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. Other than fixing the casing on your method names and lower-casing the `WB` variable, the code makes sense and is already pretty compact. If you're having performance problems is probably due to the size or complexity of your Workbook or if this is Interop code, the sheer overhead of Interop services.

Comment: Can I get the desiered sheet in a better way using linq ?

Comment: LINQ doesn't provide magical solve-everything functionality. It has its uses but this probably isn't one that would provide any benefit. What you have is simple and logical. Using LINQ just for the sake of using LINQ isn't a good approach here.

Comment: Ok, that was helpful. Is there someway I can remove the nested loop ?

Comment: Is it possible to **overload** so that it can be used in sheets from WB.Sheets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your nested loops question, you can extract all of the required names into a separate array first, then scan the array for each existing name.

```
Public Sub createNextMonthSheets(ByRef io As InputOutput)
    Dim WB As Excel.Workbook = getWorkBook(io.newClientReportHandle)
    Dim CurrMonthSheetNames As String() = clientSheetNames.FindAll(AddressOf findCurrMonthSheetNames)
    For Each sheet In WB.Sheets
        Dim name As String = sheet.Name
        If Array.Contains(CurrMonthSheetNames, name) Then
            sheet.Name = name.Replace(currMonth, nextMonth)
            sheet.Copy(After:=WB.Sheets(1))
        End If
    Next sheet
    WB.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.. that really helped.. though I was wondering that why didn't I thought of that !